# migrate application from weblogic 10 to 12c websevice.jar and webserviceclient.jar not supporting

Tags: weblogic

I am migrating the application from weblogic 10 to 12 c
I have webservice.jar and webserviceclient.jar in my class path

when i deploy application on weblogic 12c It doesnt have webservice.jar and webserviceclient.jar

is there any alternate jar . Or how can we compile the code without these jar files

Thanks 
Ramandeep S

Comment: You need the jars in your classpath for a .ear/.war file? You can force them to be in your classpath by editing the startWebLogic.sh file if that's what you need

Answer (score 1):

Create the wlfullclient.jar and use that for compile classpath. wlfullclient.jar should have everything you need. This is the way to create it: go to weblogic server lib directory, then java -jar wljarbuilder.jar -profile wlfullclient. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

everything is in :

```
wseeclient.jar
```

instead of

```
webservice.jar
```

http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/SACLT/basics.htm#i1069973

..

but the package is changed to

```
weblogic.wsee.*;
```

instead of

```
weblogic.webservice.*;
```

so make sure that you change some paths